# How to read from .txt file and show in Text View

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to get my android application to read a .txt file and display a random line in the text view,

A snippet of the code i got so far is

```
{       
    try
    { 
        java.util.ArrayList<String> lines = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fileReader; 
        BufferedReader reader; 
        fileReader = new FileReader("MyStrings.txt"); 
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

        String lineIn = reader.readLine(); //This String will hold the data brought in fron the text file.
        do
        {
        System.out.println(lineIn);
        lineIn = reader.readLine();
        }while(lineIn != null);
        reader.close();//This step is not necessary but is advised
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        //This line gets your question
        //TextView t1v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factslist);
        //TextView tv = (x.get(rand.nextInt(x.size()-1))); 
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factslist);
```

I found this through a tutorial, but i cant get it to show a random line. Any ideas whats up? ( there is some random stuff in there that isnt used)

XML File

```
      <TextView
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/factslist"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold"
android.layout_column="15" 
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps involve

```
//Give your range for random line numbers.
int min = 1;
int max = 10;

Random r = new Random();
int someRandomNo = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

String strTextToDisplay = getStreamTextByLine("MyStrings.txt", someRandomNo);

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factslist);

t.setText(strTextToDisplay);
```

Below is the usefull function to get string of particular line number of text file placed in assets folder.

```
private String getStreamTextByLine(String fileName, int lineNumber) {
            String strOut = "";
            String line = "";
            int counter = 1;
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            try {
                InputStream in = assetManager.open(fileName);
                if (in != null) {
                    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
                    while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (counter == lineNumber) {
                            strOut = line;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    in.close();
                } else {
                    Log.e("Input Stream Problem",
                            "Input stream of text file is null");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("0003:Error in get stream", e.getMessage());
            }
            return strOut;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is too advanced for me, im doing it for Android and i have no idea what to do with this :\

Comment: just copyy paste 2nd step, function getStreamTextByLine(), and call this function by giving two parameters, first takes text file name, and second takes the line number, which you want to read from text file. please ask for more detail. thanks.

Comment: I have made some change in my answer. Declared a seperate string and get string data from text file, then show that string variable in textView.

Comment: Ok let me check it out, EDIT: Where do i place step 1? I get an error on the someRandomNo bit, even if i change it to a number?

Comment: actually someRandomNo is int variable, now i have edited again, to get value of random int.

Comment: t.setText(strTextToDisplay); - On this line, the string inside the brackets isnt registering, so its coming up with an error, whys this happening =[

Comment: variabledecleratorid expected and misplaced constructs

Comment: Please make sure that, [int max] must be less than the total number of lines, in text file.

Comment: Ok it is running now, but still nothing is showing on the page in the emulator, its just blank,

Comment: Place this
Log.e("Text of stream", strTextToDisplay);

before
t.setText(strTextToDisplay);

then check result in LogCat, are you able to see your desired result in Log ?

Comment: I think theres something wrong with the way ive put the code or something, ive been stuck on this for hours

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you kind of need to use an Input Stream, Stream Reader, and Buffered reader to read from a file in android. It's not as simple as running java from your command line. This is a code excerpt from an app of mine that I heavily modified for your usage. good luck.

This code assumes the random number is within the scope of the file. If not, it will return `null`. The best way to assure that `RandNum` is within the scope of the file is to find the number of lines in the file (google that if you don't know how to do it) and perform a modulo operation such as:

```
int RandNum = //gererate random number code
RandNum = RandNum % linecount + 1;
```

`RandNum` will then be a number between 1 and the number of lines in the file.

I then pass this to our function:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public String[] GetRandLine (File file, int RandNum){

try{
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(String.valueOf(file));          
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (fis, "UTF8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (isr);

        int i = 1;
        String YourResult;

        while ((YourResult=in.readLine()) != null) { //makes sure line is not null
               if (i == RandNum) return YourResult;
               i++;
        }
        in.close();
        isr.close();
        fis.close();
                return null; //should never get here hypothetically
    }
    catch (IOException e){return null;} //Stream could not be opened
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g9w4zNwc - i changed it a little to display it in a textview, it doesnt seem to be showing anything still, am i still doing something wrong=[

Comment: well you cant really use System.out.println haha, where would it go? you should create a TextView and just use TextView.setText(debugging values). but because you want to print a whole bunch of strings, id declare an array of Strings [10] and just save the first 10 strings of the file to make sure its working. from there just use a textview to look at inidividual elements of the array. this is sloppy coding but heck, its debugging

Comment: Isnt that what the t.setText(YourResult); line does anyway?

Comment: yes but unless your testing your code in a terminal or eclipse ect where would system.out.println write to... not the screen... gerenally when Im doing debugging like that within the context of my emulator I use textview.settext() . That way I can see exactly whats happening in a realistic application of my code.